# Is it possible to write a Swift function that replaces only part of an extended grapheme cluster like ‍‍‍?

Tags: swift, string, replace, emoji, unicode-string

I want to write a function that could be used like this:

```
let ‍‍‍ = "‍‍‍".replacingFirstOccurrence(of: "", with: "")
```

Given [how odd both this string and Swift's `String` library are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618487/why-is-treated-so-strangely-in-swift-strings/43619038#43619038), is this possible in Swift?

Comment: This would indeed be a bit tricky if it needs to work with all emoji, including sequences, while also retaining the invisible characters (zero-width joiners, variation selectors and all other special cases).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [`range(of:options:range:locale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642786-range) the solution became quite concise:

```
extension String {
    func replaceFirstOccurrence(of searchString: String, with replacementString: String) -> String {
        guard let range = self.range(of: searchString, options: .literal) else { return self }
        return self.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: replacementString)
    }
}
```

This works by first finding the range of `searchString` within the instance, and if a range is found the range is replaced with `replacementString`. Otherwise the instance just returns itself. And, since the `range(of:)` method returns as soon as it finds a match, the returned range is guaranteed to be the first occurrence.

```
"221".replaceFirstOccurrence(of: "2", with: "3")                // 321
"‍‍‍".replaceFirstOccurrence(of: "\u{1f469}", with: "\u{1f468}") // ‍‍‍
```

<sup>*To clarify, the last test case converts *woman-woman-girl-boy* to *man-woman-girl-boy*.</sup>

Comment: That is indeed elegant and far easier, using the `.literal` option.

Comment: `.literal` is documented as "Exact character-by-character equivalence", but apparently "character" does not mean a Swift `Character` in this context. My guess would be that it actually means "exact Unicode scalar equivalence" or "exact UTF-16 equivalence" (since `.literal` is defined in `NSString.CompareOptions` and `NSString` is based on `unichar`).

Comment: @MartinR I think you're correct, but since you can't search with malformed UTF-16 in Swift, it essentially does mean unicode scalar equivalence.

Comment: Indeed, it makes no difference. – Perhaps that information about `.literal` would be a useful addition to your other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43619065/1187415 ?

Comment: @MartinR I guess it would be good to point out, yes. I'll edit it in there later today when I get the chance!

Comment: This also passes all my tests, and feels much more at-home in my library. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Based on the insights gained at [Why are emoji characters like 👩‍👩‍👧‍👦 treated so strangely in Swift strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618487/why-is-treated-so-strangely-in-swift-strings), a sensible approach might be to replace Unicode scalars:

```
extension String {
    func replacingFirstOccurrence(of target: UnicodeScalar, with replacement: UnicodeScalar) -> String {

        let uc = self.unicodeScalars
        guard let idx = uc.index(of: target) else { return self }
        let prefix = uc[uc.startIndex..<idx]
        let suffix = uc[uc.index(after: idx) ..< uc.endIndex]
        return "\(prefix)\(replacement)\(suffix)"
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let family1 = "‍‍‍"
print(family1.characters.map { Array(String($0).unicodeScalars) })
// [["\u{0001F469}", "\u{200D}"], ["\u{0001F469}", "\u{200D}"], ["\u{0001F467}", "\u{200D}"], ["\u{0001F466}"]]

let family2 = family1.replacingFirstOccurrence(of: "", with: "")
print(family2) // ‍‍‍
print(family2.characters.map { Array(String($0).unicodeScalars) })
// [["\u{0001F469}", "\u{200D}"], ["\u{0001F469}", "\u{200D}"], ["\u{0001F466}", "\u{200D}"], ["\u{0001F466}"]]
```

And here is a possible version which locates and replaces the Unicode scalars of an arbitrary string:

```
extension String {
    func replacingFirstOccurrence(of target: String, with replacement: String) -> String {
        let uc = self.unicodeScalars
        let tuc = target.unicodeScalars

        // Target empty or too long:
        if tuc.count == 0 || tuc.count > uc.count {
            return self
        }

        // Current search position:
        var pos = uc.startIndex
        // Last possible position of `tuc` within `uc`:
        let end = uc.index(uc.endIndex, offsetBy: tuc.count - 1)

        // Locate first Unicode scalar
        while let from = uc[pos..<end].index(of: tuc.first!) {
            // Compare all Unicode scalars:
            let to = uc.index(from, offsetBy: tuc.count)
            if !zip(uc[from..<to], tuc).contains(where: { $0 != $1 }) {
                let prefix = uc[uc.startIndex..<from]
                let suffix = uc[to ..< uc.endIndex]
                return "\(prefix)\(replacement)\(suffix)"
            }
            // Next search position:
            uc.formIndex(after: &pos)
        }

        // Target not found.
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: Martin but why playground print  UnicodeScalarView same after you apply replacing ?

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk: I inadvertently printed `family1` instead of `family2`, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: How about this let b = "‍‍‍".characters.map{String($0) == "" ? "" : $0}

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk: That would replace *all* occurrences, not just the first (if it worked)

Comment: But i have a trouble it is replacing only one emoji. And i could not understand why.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk: Have a look at OP's previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618487/why-is-treated-so-strangely-in-swift-strings, which is exactly about that problem.

Comment: This fails to compile with some strings, like: `""`, `"multichar"` or `""`

Comment: @BenLeggiero: Because that are not Unicode scalars. – You could define the second parameter as `with replacement: String`, but I am not sure if the results always make sense.

Comment: I see... Well, I'll need the final solution to replace a sequence of scalars with another one, so I'll try some stuff on my end.

Comment: @BenLeggiero: I have added another variant, perhaps that is what you are looking for.

Comment: That last variant passes all my tests! :D