# Count how many times a special character (non-spacing mark) occurs in a string in Swift

Tags: swift, search, unicodescalar

This function searches how many times a character appears in a string:

```
let str = "الصَّبَاْحُ جَمِيْلٌ"
let char: Character = "َ"


func SpecificLetterCount(_ str:String, _ char:Character) -> Int {
let letters = Array(str); var count = 0
for letter in letters {
    if letter == char {
        count += 1
    }
}
return count
}

print(SpecificLetterCount(str, char)) //Prints 0 , where in fact it should find it 3 times in that string!
```

In this case the result is 
 0 , where in fact it should find it 3 times in that string!, but because it is a non-spacing mark (a special character) it can't find it by itself. The same happens with this character: ( e +  ́  ) = é , where I can't find ( ́  ) by itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to work with unicode scalars instead of characters (which are so-called *extended grapheme clusters*).

*Unsafe* example:

```
func SpecificLetterCount(_ str:String, _ char:Character) -> Int {
    var count = 0
    for s in  str.unicodeScalars {
        print(s)
        if s == char.unicodeScalars.first! {
            count += 1
        }
    }

    return count
}
```

The code is unsafe because of `char.unicodeScalars.first!` which expects the char to consist of only one scalar. I leave it as an exercise to make this function safe.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the excellent insight from [Why are emoji characters like 👩‍👩‍👧‍👦 treated so strangely in Swift strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618487/why-are-emoji-characters-like-treated-so-strangely-in-swift-strings/43619065#43619065), you can do a *literal search:*

```
func specificLetterCount(_ str:String, _ char:Character) -> Int {
    var count = 0
    var pos = str.startIndex
    while let range = str[pos...].range(of: String(char), options: .literal) {
        count += 1
        pos = range.upperBound
    }
    return count
}
```

This gives the expected result:

```
let str = "الصَّبَاْحُ جَمِيْلٌ"
let char: Character = "َ"
print(specificLetterCount(str, char)) // 3
```