# `contains("\n")` of `String` return false while there is a return in the string

Tags: swift

```
let a = """
a
️b
"""
a.contains("\n") // false
```

It seems there is a strange character in the string right after the return.

```
a.forEach(){ c in
    print(Character(String(c)).asciiValue)
}
```

```
Output: 
Optional(97)
Optional(10) // the return 
nil
Optional(98)
```

Is this a bug of `contains` method that results in negatively recognizing the return character while it is followed by some strange ones?

Comment: Related (and possibly a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/43618487/1187415.

Comment: In particular, the modified contains() method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43619065/1187415 returns true in your case.

Comment: Note that I have undeleted and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I printed out the unicode scalars in your string:

```
print(a.unicodeScalars.map { $0.value })
// [97, 10, 65039, 98]
```

And found out that your string indeed contains the line feed character `\n`, which is the value `10`. However, it is followed by U+FE0F (65039), one of those [variation selectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block)) in unicode.

The overload of `contains` you are calling here is `contains(StringProtocol)`, not `contains(Character)`. The former will perform a "smarter" kind of comparison, or as the Xcode's Quick Help documentation calls it, "non-literal":

> **Summary**
>
> Returns true iff other is non-empty and contained within `self` by case-sensitive, non-literal search.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Equivalent to `self.rangeOfString(other) != nil`

I can't seem to find this documentation online though... All I could find was [this discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/was-the-string-contains-method-changed-in-swift-4/6979/3) showing `contains` is smart enough to recognise that "ß" means "ss".

Anyway, the point is, `contains` does not do a character-by-character search. It does whatever it think "makes sense".

Here are a few ways to make it print `true`:

- If you add the variation selector in to the argument to `contains`, it prints `true`:

  ```
    print(a.contains("\n️")) // you can't see it, but there *is* a variation selector after the n
  ```
- Check whether the `unicodeScalars` contain the `\n` character:

  ```
    print(a.unicodeScalars.contains("\n"))
  ```
- Use the `contains(Character)` overload:

  ```
    print(a.contains("\n" as Character))
  ```
- Use `range(of:)` with `.literal` option:

  ```
    print(a.rangeOfString("\n", options: [.literal]) != nil)
  ```