Swift throws errors for certain emojis
I'm copying code from a beginner swift project and the video has
enum Emoji {
    case , , , , ‍❤️‍‍
}

However as soon as I type the ‍❤️‍‍ emoji I get a Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by '; error. This only happens with the ‍❤️‍‍ emoji and all other emojis I've tried works fine. What is wrong with my code? Is there something special about the code behind the ‍❤️‍‍ emoji? My full code is here:
import SwiftUI

enum Emoji {
    case , , , , ‍❤️‍‍
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

I tried searching up this error but nothing related to my issue came up. I also searched up issues related to emojis in swift but nothing came up. I expect to just get no errors and everything to run smoothly

It's a combination of multiple emojis: https://emojipedia.org/emoji-zwj-sequence, Use it as rawValue instead case coupleKiss = "‍❤️‍‍"

You can check this discussion which has some clarification about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618487/why-are-emoji-characters-like-treated-so-strangely-in-swift-strings?rq=1

As you know, enum cases need to be identifiers, and not all characters can be in an identifier. Refer to the language reference for what ranges of Unicode code points are allowed in an identifier.
As the AxB's answer says, ‍❤️‍‍ breaks down into 6 code points.
U+1F468   MAN
U+200D  ‍   ZERO WIDTH JOINER
U+2764  ❤   HEAVY BLACK HEART
U+FE0F  ️   VARIATION SELECTOR-16
U+200D  ‍   ZERO WIDTH JOINER
U+1F48B   KISS MARK
U+200D  ‍   ZERO WIDTH JOINER
U+1F468   MAN

Every one of these code points are allowed to be used in an identifier, except ❤. The list of ranges in the language reference does not include U+2764. Excerpt:

U+2070–U+20CF, U+2100–U+218F, U+2460–U+24FF, or U+2776–U+2793


This is because this emoji ‍❤️‍‍ is a compound emoji. It's made by combining multiple emojis, compared to others which are just a single emoji. We can test this via following code
func printUnicodes(emoji: String) {
    for scalar in emoji.unicodeScalars {
        print(String(format: "U+%04X", scalar.value))
    }
}

if we call the function with this emoji  ‍❤️‍‍ we get following output, which shows multiple unicodes of a compound emoji,
U+1F468
U+200D
U+2764
U+FE0F
U+200D
U+1F468

and when we run it with this emoji  we only get one value,
U+1F921

Now, to solve this what you can do is instead of using emoji directly as the enum case, represent the emoji as a string like this,
enum Emoji: String {
    case clown = ""
    case poop = ""
    case skull = ""
    case smile = ""
    case couple = "‍❤️‍‍"
}


"it contains multiple Unicode code points" is not enough of a reason. name contains 4 code points, yet it is a valid identifier. (with a skin tone modifier) and (three emojis) are also valid identifiers.
